# Using TikZ breaks foot margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script

I have got some unexpected Problem using Ti*k*Z in LaTeX. 
When I add Ti*k*Z via `\usepackage{tikz}`, the foot margin is doubled. Any ideas in how to solve this? Or where the Problem is?

Minimal Examples:
All is fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
    Fooooo
\end{document}
```

And broken footer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    Baaaar
\end{document}
```

PS: I am using TeXlive 2014.20141024 (Packages from Debian jessie)

Comment: I don't see any change on my system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can not reproduce this behaviour. Please load the package `showframe` and you will see that both your examples look the same. Maybe you are missing some code in your MWE which is needed in order to show the issue.

Comment: I checked the example on 2 different machines both with the same behaviour. With exactly this code :( Okey funny thing with showframe - same behaviour as with tikz. The thing is: without i got an footmargin about 2cm with i get round about 4cm...  But ill print it later to cross check....

Comment: I see how you can measure the margin using package `showframe`, but how do you do it if the page is almost completely empty?

Comment: The offset of the page numbering. I also made some tests with the lipsum package with same result. Measured using different pdf viewers and looked both files pre/and post tikz ...

Comment: The pagination stays on it's very spot for Ti*k*Z, `lipsum`, `showframe`... This should be really robust. Please delete your auxiliary files and test again. Are your packages up to date?

Comment: OMG *LoL* i found the problem .... didnt see this before: The Page Size changes from A4 to US-Letter ...but why...? Edit: no wait... seems to change from Letter to A4

Comment: Seems that komascript ignores the a4paper and the paper=a4 option...

Comment: Use `\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize=auto]{scrreprt}` if your KOMA-Script version is older than 3.17.

Comment: Does any class use `paper=a4`? `geometry` will recognise it, but `a4paper` is standard as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{typearea}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

to ensure that `A4` is used even if your KOMA Script version is older than 3.17

---

Explanation:

All KOMA-Script classes load package `typearea` to set the page layout.

With KOMA-Script versions older than 3.17 the `typearea` option `pagesize` needs to be set to send the page size information to the output driver. If this option was not set and no other package sends this information the default paper format of your installation is used.

Note that the standard classes also do not send this information to the output driver. You have to load a package like `geometry` or `typerarea` to do this.

Since version 3.17 `typearea` option `pagesize=auto` is set by default. To get the former behaviour you have to use `pagesize=false` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my Problem KOMAScriptVersion was/is v3.12 2013/12/19